# PowerQuery writing a calculated column formula that uses a dynamic parameter

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to create a calculated column that uses a parameter. The parameter is a table within excel that an individual can change for PM_Month and CM_Month. The calculation should be PM_Month - CM_Month. But I receive an error. I believe the error is because the Record.Field calculation is literally trying to take the Text from the parameter and subtracting it. I want the data in the columns of Month 1 and 2 to be subtracted.

This is my parameter
[image: My Parameters]

Here is my M code that reshapes my data
[image: My Pivot Code]

Here is the error in the Chg column. Instead of an error I expect the Chg column to subtract Jan and Feb which would equal 0
[image: Output]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76230232/edit) to include your code as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically forgot the [Value] part

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
PM =  Parameters{0}[Value],
CM =  Parameters{1}[Value],
z=Table.AddColumn(Source,"Subtract", each Record.Field(_,CM) - Record.Field(_,PM))
in z
```

or, if I was writing it, this way, so that additions to, or sort order of, the Parameters table wouldn't ruin my code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
PM =  Table.SelectRows(Parameters, each ([Parameter] = "PM_Month")){0}[Value],
CM =  Table.SelectRows(Parameters, each ([Parameter] = "CM_Month")){0}[Value],
z=Table.AddColumn(Source,"Subtract", each Record.Field(_,CM) - Record.Field(_,PM))
in z
```

[image]